# Lower Bounds for the Roots of Polynomials

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series, taylor-series, lower-bounds

I'm interested in the "size" of the roots of a sequence of Taylor Polynomials of an entire function.

**For example**, consider $\mathrm f(z) = \mathrm e^z$. The Taylor Polynomials, or $k$-jets, are 
$$\mathrm P_k(z) = 1 + z + \frac{1}{2!}z^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{k!}z^k$$

I want to find the best possible lower bound for the modulus of the roots for any given $\mathrm P_k$. Let
$$ L_k := \min\{ |w| : \mathrm P_k(w)=0 \}$$
I would like to know the limit of $L_k$ as $k \to \infty$. In this case, I think that $L_k \to \infty$ and $k \to \infty$.

I've used the [standard bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Based_on_the_Rouch.C3.A9_theorem) based on the Rouché theorem, but this does **not** give a useful lower bound; it gives a lower bound independent of $k$. In the case of $\mathrm e^z$, the lower bound is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I was hoping for a bound dependent on $k$, so that I could then find the limit of the bound as $k \to \infty$ and show that $L_k \to \infty$.

**In general:** Given a sequence of polynomials, how could I find the greatest lower bound of the modulus of the roots for each of these polynomials? Specifically, I am interested in the limit of these lower bounds as the polynomials tend to an infinite power series.

Comment: Maybe, integral representation makes sense: $-(k-1)! P_k(z) e^{-z}=\int_{-\infty}^z w^{k}e^{-w}dw$.

Comment: It's obvious that $L_k\to\infty$, with no calculation whatsoever, from the fact the Taylor polynomials converge locally uniformly to $f$, which has no zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is related to the Szego curve, which has been much studied (just google it). A lower bound for the roots is given by $W(1/e)n=0.278..n$ where $W$ is the Lambert function.
Theorem 4 of http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub/paper_184.pdf should give you an expansion of a lower bound, up to order $O(1/n)$.

Comment: This is an excellent reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure how you are using Rouche's theorem, but if you make $f(z) = e^z,$ while $g(z)=e^z - P_k(z),$ then the minimum of $|e^z|$ on $|z|\leq R$ is $\exp(-R),$ so as long as this is larger than the remainder term, your polynomial has no zeros in the disk (by Rouche). Since the remainder term (the [Lagrange formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) is the easiest) decreases superexponentially (in $k$) you are cooking with gas.

Comment: Does not this argument work pointwise without Rouche?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Indeed, it does!